# pandas count value result wrong answer / can not recongnise the same values

Tags: python, pandas, count

```
import pandas as pd
file= pd.read_csv("test_data.csv")
file['ORIGIN'].value_counts()
```

the Result is strange, It catogorized the nationality to two values like this:

```
> Egyptian                                                        14939
> Indian                                                          11934
> Indian                                                           9803
> Egyptian                                                         9465
> British                                                          4568
> British                                                          4317
> Name: ORIGIN, dtype: int64
```

The CSV file on the link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YvkuUJB7NHIwqN-SlywuFIuiFR1779yB/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I suspect one of them has extra whitespace.

Comment: Try `file['ORIGIN'].str.strip().value_counts()`. Does it change anything?

Comment: Look at `file['ORIGIN'].unique()` to see exactly what the values are

Comment: @Barmar .. I already checked that ,, no white space

Comment: I'm not agree with that @almegdadi. Check my answer below. I used your provided file.

Comment: @Corralien.. Works perfectly .. Thanx :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suggested by @ALollz, use `unique`:

```
>>> file['ORIGIN'].unique()
array(['Indian                                                      ',  # HERE
       'Egyptian                                                    ',  # HERE
       'British                                                     ',  # HERE
       'Egyptian                                                  ',
       'British                                                   ',
       'Indian                                                    '],
      dtype=object)
```

*See the extra whitespace to the 3 first lines suspected by @Barmar*

Output of `value_counts` after `str.strip`:

```
>>> file['ORIGIN'].str.strip().value_counts()
Egyptian    24404
Indian      21737
British      8885
Name: ORIGIN, dtype: int64
```